# Windows Phone app using Light sensors closes after few seconds

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need help with a problem on Windows Phone. I am doing some tests with the sensors (Windows.Devices.Sensors) and I try to do something useless but funny: read music (with a MediaElement) and change the volume depending on the brightness measured by the light sensor!

Everything works fine for a few seconds and suddenly, the application closes on my test device (Lumia 925 with WP 8.1) but the test is still in progress in Visual Studio. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

    // Timer
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10.0);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    var lightSensor = LightSensor.GetDefault();
    var lightSensorValue = Math.Truncate(lightSensor.GetCurrentReading().IlluminanceInLux);
    TextBlock_SensorValue.Text = lightSensorValue.ToString();
    MediaElement_music.Volume = lightSensorValue > 100 ? 1.0 : lightSensorValue / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: did you try turning down the refresh rate? every 10ms is quite often

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I'll try that, it's true that 10ms is quite often but it's strange that the application closes by itself without error reported on Visual Studio.

Comment: When I use the method described in the example on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor, everything seems to work great. Even if my test code is not optimal, I can't explain this issue!

Comment: Do you see anything interesting in the Output window of Visual Studio?  I'm also surprised you can set the Text property of a TextBlock from that method - usually you have to make sure you're on the UI thread by using the Dispatcher...

Comment: @gregstoll No error appears on Visual Studio, everything continues to run on that side while the application is closed on my phone! About threads, it seems to me that with a DispatcherTimer, you don't have this problem (as opposed to a basic timer that raises issues of threading), but i'm not sure about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few questions arise when looking at your code. Why are you using a timer a don't use the event as described in the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor) you provided in the comment?

For your Visual Studio issue please check that you have the option Thrown enabled under *Debug / Exceptions...* for the CLR. VS will break on exceptions you may otherwise just not see.

[image: Enable to break on Exceptions Thrown in Visual Studio]

Something else to note is that your timer at 10 MS is really quick and your handler code may get called multiple times which may lead to some awkward side effects.

Edit: I could not reproduce your error by the way. My app never closed/crashed during multiple minutes. Tested on a Lumia 920 with WP Silverlight 8.1 Project. Only difference was that the page caching on my end was not enabled.